# String in a class

Tags: c++, string, function, class

I was working on a project and I've had a question: when I call a class that contain a `string str`, does the code create a string every time or it use the string I've already created?
For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    

class exClass {
public:
    void exVoid ( string valueStr )
    {
        str = "Hi";
        cout << str;
    }

private:
    string str;
};

int main()
{
    exClass myClass;

    string stringMain;

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "Insert value of str: ";
        cin >> stringMain;
        myClass.exVoid(stringMain);
    }
}
```

so the question is: every time I call exClass, the class create the string str or it do that only once (when I call it for the first time)?

Comment: You are effectively creating a new `std::string` object every time you call `exVoid`, because the `valueStr` argument is such an object that needs to be created and copied into each call. However, there is only one `myClass.str` object.

Answer (score 2):

Following the flow of the program:

First you create an instance of `exClass` named `myClass`. This happens once.

Then you create a `string` named `stringMain`. This also happens once.

After that, you have an endless loop `while(1)`. Inside this loop you:

1. Print on the output
2. Get input
3. Call function `exVoid()`

So, you create one instance of `class` `exClass` with one member `str` and use the same `str` (through your function) endlessly inside your loop.

Something to think about is the function argument. You never really use it. For it to have meaning in you code, you can do something like:

```
   void exVoid ( string valueStr )
   {
            str = valueStr;
            cout << str;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're creating a copy of your input string every time you call exVoid. You can make it more efficient if you use a reference:

```
void exVoid(const std::string &value) {
    ...
}
```

The way you're calling it from `main`, you're thus passing a reference to `stringMain`, but by making it const, you know your method won't mess with it.